# ls -ltr dirname* in perl

Tags: perl, grep

I need to find for a certain dirname, i have a code which greps for the latest-file . Could someone help me to find the ls -ltr dirname* without using the ls -ltr command in the perl script. Below code may help:

```
my $dir = "/abc/pqr/xyz";
opendir(my $DH, $dir) or die "Error opening $dir: $!";
my %files = map { $_ => (stat("$dir/$_"))[9] } grep(! /^\.\.?$/, readdir($DH));
closedir($DH);
my @sorted_files = sort { $files{$b} <=> $files{$a} } (keys %files);
print "the file is $sorted_files[0] \n";
```

I need a to find a dir name as new_123 in /abc/pqr/xyz. As ls -ltr new*, as these directories are created everyday so looking for new*.

Comment: Do you really want `-l`, or just `ls -tr`? Because the ling listing has a number of heuristics which can be hard to emulate exactly (display year no not, time or just date, adjust volumn widths, etc).

Comment: Also unless you skip all dotfiles (not just current and parent directory) you get `ls -a` behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Its a bit unclear what you are asking for, but:

> I need a to find a dir name as new_123 in /abc/pqr/xyz. As ls -ltr
>   new*, as these directories are created everyday so looking for new*.

For that, you can use [glob](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html).

My PERL is a bit rusty but I think this would do it:

```
while (my $dir = glob("new*")) {

        next unless (-d "$dir");
        print "$dir\n";

}
```

If system calls are not a restriction, you can use find:

`find /some/path/ -type d -name "new*"`

Comment: Yes I need a to find a dir name as new_123 in /abc/pqr/xyz. As ls -ltr new* but not by using the command.

Comment: Could some-one help me to do ls -ltr new* in a perl script and grep for the latest new*. Please help on this